# How to create multiple pools on LEMP Stack, PHP 8.1?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, php, php-fpm, socket

I need to optimize my web app performance, with that in mind I created two PHP-FPM pools for frontend and backend and their respective users. Both pools are listening to different sockets on `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d`.

**fpm-backend.conf**

```shell
...
user = fpm-backend
group = fpm-backend

...

listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm-backend.sock
...
```

**fpm-frontend.conf**

```shell
...
user = fpm-frontend
group = fpm-frontend

...

listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm-frontend.sock
...
```

I removed the default config file **www.conf** to not take precedence. But the sockets are only generated for only one of them (e.g **fpm-backend.conf**), regardless of the times I restart PHP-FPM service. I need sockets for both of them to optimize my web app on Nginx, please help!